# Laravel VueJs API Route returns 404 Not Found Error

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I am setting up my Laravel vuejs app in a Windows 10 Desktop with Apache24 and PHP7.4 installed.

After installed Apache24 and PHP in my windows, when i visit localhost:8080 it loads the web home page, however when i try to access the API such GET localhost:8080/api/health in my browser, it return 404.

I did `php artisan route:list` and the route is present.

The location of the files for my project is in "Apache24/htdocs"

I have added the Virtual host as below for my httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/public"
    ServerName "localhost"
    <Directory C:/Apache24/htdocs/ >
         AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My routes/web.php looks like below

```
Route::get('{any}', function ($any = null) {

    if (strpos($any, 'shop/') === 0) {
        return view('layouts.vue_shop');
    } else {
        return view('layouts.vue');
    }
})->where('any', '^(?!api).*$');
```

My routes/api.php

```
Route::get('health', 'HealthController')->name('api.check.health');
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
You did not give the full path of the directory in apache conf.

From this

```
 <Directory C:/Apache24/htdocs>
         AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

To this

```
 <Directory C:/Apache24/htdocs/public >
         AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Hi @Usman, tried this and restarted Apache and still getting 404 not found error for my API route.

Comment: You sure that htdocs has the public folder?